# Use of using X::func in public

Tags: c++, using

Recently I came across a code shown below. What does it achieve? How can we bring a private part of an object to public space? I am aware of the usage of using BX::f , if the derived class hides the base class function.

```
 class BX { 
 public: 
 void f(int); 
 void f(char const*); 
 void g(); 
}; 
class DX : private BX { 
 public: 
 using BX::f; 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes the `f` functions public members of `DX` but without making anything else from `BX` accessible.

The functions are already public members of `BX` so this does not break encapsulation.